# Format an Input after changing select in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I make my first steps in AngularJS. I use this directive from this [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/8mT3EA/preview) to format my Input on the fly. It works perfect.

Now, I use a function called updateCountry(), which listens to my select and changes dynamically the locale. It also works correct.

**Question:** The Input still remains in the old locale format. If I click into the Input, the format will be changed to the new locale format.
How can I 'trigger' the directive or format the ng-model='item-cost' after updating my select?

Thank you for your tips!

**HTML**

```
<input ng:model="item.cost" blur-to-currency amount="stake" class="table-inputs unitprice">
```

**SCRIPT UPDATE SELECT**

```
$scope.updateCountry = function() {
// format the existing value of the input with the new locale
};
```

**SCRIPT DIRECTIVE**

```
.directive('blurToCurrency', function($filter){
  return {
    scope: {
      amount  : '='
    },
    link: function(scope, el, attrs){
      el.val($filter('currency' )(scope.amount, ''));

      el.bind('focus', function(){
        el.val(scope.amount);
      });

      el.bind('input', function(){
        scope.amount = el.val();
        scope.$apply();
      });

      el.bind('blur', function(){
        el.val($filter('currency')(scope.amount, ''));
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Can post the code including the select ?

Comment: It would be really good if you can put your code in a plunker and provide the url here. Others can easily fork the plunker and try to correct it

Comment: O.k. thank you, I will put my code in a plunker and come back later again.

Comment: Here we go...Here is my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/JgpQaIXKLDVOH0C7ZEso?p=preview)